# MyPy "cannot assign" error for psycopg2 connection returned by contextmanager

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, mypy

I am using a context manager and "with" statement to yield a connection created by psycopg2. Now MyPy is throwing errors when I try to pass said connection to another function that is expecting a parameter of type psycopg2.extensions.connection:

```
Argument of type "_T_co@contextmanager" cannot be assigned to parameter "conn" of type "connection | None" in function "some_function"
```

My code to get the connection is as follows:

```
with get_cnx() as conn:
    some_function(conn)
```

get_cnx() itself yields a psycopg2 connection from a ThreadedConnectionPool.

The code works, and I don't want to just ignore the MyPy errors. How do specify the correct type in this case.

UPDATE - get_cnx() code:

```
@contextmanager
def get_cnx(customer_id):
    config: dict = <do logic to get connection configurations based on customer id>
    
    pool = psycopg2.poool.ThreadedConnectionPool(**config)
    cnx = db_pool.getconn()

    try:
         yield cnx
    finally:
         db_pool.putconn(cnx)
```

Comment: Please add `get_cnx` code (or signature at least) too, it is related.

Comment: @SUTerliakov I added as much of the code from get_cnx() as I was allowed. But basically, a connection from the connection pool is yielded.

Comment: Nice! I suppose the problem is that `get_cnx` is untyped. Could you try adding type annotations to it (probably `def get_cnx(customer_id: int) -> typing.Iterator[psycopg2.connection]`)?